# How to integrate complex exponential??

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Consider
$$\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2} } e^{i2\pi f} \,df  = \int^{\frac{1}{2} }_{-\frac{1}{2} } \cos(2 \pi f)\, df$$

Why do we only look at the real part? What about the imaginary part $i\sin(2\pi f)$?

What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: It is pretty odd to use $f$ as as dummy variable!

Comment: *One question mark (?) per sentence is sufficient.*

Comment: the limits of integration are? sorry I wear glasses:)

Comment: Please do stop using $\,f\,$ as a dummy variable...it almost hurts!

Comment: I suspect this is from a Fourier transform or something and so "f" is for "frequency".

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, right click on some rendered math, then go to `Math Settings > Scale All Math...` and enter a number bigger than 100.

Comment: @AntonioVargas thank you for the advice, but I gave the comment as a joke and it missed a minus sign in the limits of the integral.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Haha, I just checked the edit history and now I see what you mean!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: the odd dummy variable must be because of the odd function :)

Comment: @AntonioVargas, thanks a lot. I never realized right click on equations would bring those special options.

Comment: I use f for "frequency" as a dummy variable also. It's good for variables to be slightly self-documenting when they can be even in math, where we insist on using single letters for variable names.

Answer (score 12):

$$\int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}e^{2\pi ix}\,dx=\left.\frac{1}{2\pi i}e^{2\pi ix}\right|_{-1/2}^{1/2}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(e^{\pi i}-e^{-\pi i}\right)= \frac{1}{\pi}\sin\pi  \\ \int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2}\cos (2\pi x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(2\pi x)\Bigg|_{-1/2}^{1/2}=\frac{1}{2\pi}(\sin\pi-\sin(-\pi))=\frac{1}{\pi}\sin\pi    $$

Comment: What would happen if the limits of the integral are [0, 1] instead? It should lead to the same solution, right?

Answer (score 9):

Simply put, the reason is that it's an integral that is symmetric around $f=0$, and because sin is an odd function, the integral of the sin component must be zero.

Comment: This is true only (!) for symmetric interval of integration. So, if you have a symmetric interval of integration, then the integral of the odd function should be $0$ and for the even funct the interval should be halved and the integral should be doubled. :)

Comment: Yes, it's only for a symmetric interval of integration. Which is why I said "it's an integral that is symmetric around $f=0$".

Answer (score 2):

As the sine function is odd, the integral over a symmetric range is null.

In this particular case, as you are integrating over a whole period, you can also trade the cosine for a sine, and

$$\int^{\frac{1}{2} }_{-\frac{1}{2} } \cos(2 \pi f)\,df=\int^{\frac{1}{2} }_{-\frac{1}{2} } \sin(2 \pi f)\,df=0\ !$$